# How to close child window from parent window onload?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, switch-statement

I am trying to open a child pop up window when the parent window goes to a different case inside of a switch and case statement, and then close that child window when the parent window goes to another different case:

```
case "1": 
    $nextDecision = "
        <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
          <input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\" value=\"val1\">message<br>
          <input type=\"submit\">
        </form>";
    ?>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="javascripts.js"></script>
    <body onload="javascript:openWin()"></body>
    <?php
    break;
case "2": 
    $nextDecision = "
        <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
               <input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\" value=\"val2\">message<br>
           <input type=\"submit\">
        </form>";
    ?>
    <body onload="javascript:closeWin()"></body>
    <?php
    break;
```

javascripts.js:

```
function openWin() {
   myWindow=window.open("file/popup.html", "name", "width=200, height=100");
}
function closeWin() {
   myWindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to close child window on body load, which doesn't have access to child window.  Try to close it before parent window reloads..

```
function closeWin() {
   document.getElementById('choice').value='val2';
   myWindow.close();
 }

<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
   <input type=\"radio\" id=\"choice\" name=\"choice\" onsubmit="closeWin()" value=\"val2\">message<br>
   <input type=\"submit\" >
</form>";
```

Comment: How do I do that? Would I just do `<script>closeWin();</script>`? And body onload has access to open a child window. So it should be able to close it, right?

Comment: Correct! U shd close the child before u reload the parent

Comment: I tried to check if the button was clicked in that same switch statement, and moved `openWin()` to the beginning of the case. `<script>
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = closeWin();
</script>` I put that after the form, but when I reload the page, I see the pop up open, and then quickly close. Well, the pop up closed, so at least we're getting somewhere :)

Comment: U can also attach closeWin() in form tag's onsubmit event listener. Check my edit:

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you! But for future reference, how does the HTML tag understand that that's a javascript method that I defined, without using a script tag?

Comment: One last question, is it possible to close the pop up when the page goes from one case statement to another? i want the pop up to stay there until I'm at a different case, and putting `onsubmit` in a form on a different case doesn't work.

Comment: no dude...its not possible..because as soon as u leave the page all your javascript variables destroyed automatically..so myWindow variable gets reset at the time you submit the page...

Comment: Interesting. Even if it's in a switch statement, and not going from one web page to another? Or what if I had a `$nextDecision`, and use an if statement to check if the submit button was pressed, and if it was, the `$nextDecision` would change, and I could put the `onsubmit` in that form? Because then the case doesn't change, and the javascript variables are still there.

Comment: but on submission your form submits, isn't it? and if form submits, page automatically get refreshed.

Comment: Yes but I can make an if statement saying "if you submit this form, don't go to a different case. Instead, just change the form without leaving the page." That way, the page doesnt reload. I've dont that if statement before with a textbox. The pag stays the same. The form is the only thing that changes

Comment: in that case u ll have to change the form at client side. i.e on javascript side

Comment: Like store it in a cookie? Though I don't know if you can store a forn in a cookie. Would it be possible to store the javascript function into a cookie or session?

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks for helping, though :) I think I'll ask again and see if anyone can figure out how to do it.